# if..else works inside IIFy but doesn't inside event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

This code works exactly as intended:

```
(function(){
  var $winWidth = $(window).width();
 $( "#stop" ).prepend( "<p>Actual window width: " + $winWidth + "</p>" ); 
 if ($winWidth < 700) {
   $('.cycle-slideshow').attr('data-cycle-carousel-visible', '3');
 } else if ($winWidth < 1000) {
   $('.cycle-slideshow').attr('data-cycle-carousel-visible', '6');
 } else {
   $('.cycle-slideshow').attr('data-cycle-carousel-visible', '9');
 }
}());
```

But this one happily shows width dynamically, as intended, but refuses support the same if ... else

```
$(window).on('resize',function() {
      var $winWidth = $(window).width();
      $('#stop p').remove();
      $( "#stop" ).prepend( "<p>Actual window width: " + $winWidth + "</p>" );
   if ($winWidth < 700) {
   $('.cycle-slideshow').attr('data-cycle-carousel-visible', '3');
 } else if ($winWidth < 1000) {
   $('.cycle-slideshow').attr('data-cycle-carousel-visible', '6');
 } else {
   $('.cycle-slideshow').attr('data-cycle-carousel-visible', '9');
 }
    });
```

Please, can I get some explanations?
The pen is here: http://codepen.io/462960/pen/yyKrWP?editors=1010
I have even tried this one pattern without success:

```
$(window).on('resize',function() {
      var $winWidth = $(window).width();
      var atTribute;
      $('#stop p').remove();
      $( "#stop" ).prepend( "<p>Actual window width: " + $winWidth + "</p>" );
   if ($winWidth < 700) {
  atTribute = '3';
 } else if ($winWidth < 1000) {
  atTribute = '6';
 } else {
  atTribute = '9'; 
 }
  $('.cycle-slideshow').attr('data-cycle-carousel-visible', atTribute);
    });
```

Could you reassure me that I have not misused var reassignment in the last one.

Comment: *What* does not work?

Comment: Tried your pen, the if .. else *is* working, so you'll have to clarify

Comment: My apology, guys, for a bit unclear explanation. The problem occurs with event listener i.e. .on('resize'...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if...else in your code is working fine. If you inspect the carousel and watch the data-cycle-carousel-visible attribute it is changing as intended on resize.

I assume the reason your IIFE is working as intended is because it is executing before the page is finished loading, which is likely when the cycle2 carousel plugin is run. At that point your attribute has been set to the correct number of slides.

When you change the attribute on resize, it is only changing the attribute in the DOM. The carousel plugin you are using doesn't watch for changes to that attribute, and therefore the visible number of slides does not change.

I did a little digging around and found that others were also looking for similar functionality with this plugin, so this link may help you move forward: https://github.com/malsup/cycle2/issues/68